# PHP DOM: How do I replace the DocumentType node in my XML document?

Tags: php, dom, traversal

I'm writing a script to clean up the so-called HTML document that MS Word creates when you Save As "Web Page, Filtered". I want the resulting document to be valid XHTML1.

The first thing I want to do is to change the !DOCTYPE so it will be `XHTML 1.0 Strict` instead of `...4.0 Transitional`.

I wrote code that looked as if it should work, but when I run it I get a `Segmentation fault` from PHP. At first, I thought this was occurring in the `save` function, but after adding some `echo` statements for debugging I now think that the problem is at the places marked `{{{1}}}` and `{{{2}}}` in the code (below).

Here's what I think is going on: at `{{{1}}}` I am iterating through the `DOMNodeList`, treating it as if it were an ordinary array that I can traverse with `foreach`.

But at {{{2}}} I change the parent's subnode list. I suspect this breaks my `foreach`: either the `DOMNodeList` or my `foreach` pointer becomes invalid.

So what is the "right" way to make changes to a a DOM tree while you're traversing it? I came up with two possible options:

1. Copy the DOMNodeList into an ordinary array:

   $nodelist = [];
   foreach ($node->childNodes as $subnode) {
       $nodelist[] = $subnode;
       // Or perhaps an object that contains the appropriate code and parameters for the change I want to make
   }
   foreach ($nodelist as $subnode) {
       // make the appropriate change
   }
2. Traverse the DOM tree, but do not make any changes. Instead, create an array of all the places where I want to make changes. When finished, go through that array and make the changes.
3. Maybe there's some "official" way of doing this????

The relevant parts of my code below:

```
<?   
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($htmFName);
    $trav = new DOMTraverser($dom);

    $storyParms = new StoryParams("some string");
    $callback = new StoryDocCallback($htmFName);

    $trav->traverse($callback, $storyParms);
    $dom->save("y");

class DOMTraverser
{
    private $docNode;
    private $callback;
    private $param;

    public function __construct(DOMNode $node)
    {
        $this->docNode = $node;
    }

    public function traverse(GeneralCallBack $cb, $param)
    {
        $this->callback = $cb;
        $this->param = $param;
        $this->traverseNode($this->docNode);
    }

    public function traverseNode($node)
    {
        $this->callback->callBefore($node, $this->param);
        if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
{{1}}       foreach ($node->childNodes as $subnode) {
                if($subnode != null) {
                    $this->traverseNode($subnode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class StoryDocCallback implements GeneralCallback
{
    public function callbefore($node, $param)
    {
        $name = $node->nodeName;
        if (is_a($node, "DOMDocumentType")) {
            $this->repairDocType($node);
            return;
        }
        ...
    }

    protected function repairDocType(DOMNode $node)
    {
        $impl = new DomImplementation();
        $rootName = "html";
        $pubID = "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN";
        $sysID = "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd";
        $newDocType = $impl->createDocumentType($rootName, $pubID, $sysID);

        $parent = $node->parentNode;
{{2}}   $rc = $parent->replaceChild($newDocType, $node);
        assert($rc != false);
    }
...
}
```